# Jquery New Window URL Change of Parent Window

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

i am trying to open a new window from jquery and i it gets open but the problem is it changes the current window url

For example:
i am on **www.examples.com/exmaple1.aspx?q=1** and then on some button click i execute a new window open command with url as below
**www.examples.com/example2.aspx?q=12&q1=12**

the new window gets open but the URL querystring of the new window gets appended to current window

in javascript i write code as

```
window.open("examples2.aspx?q=12&q1=12","NEW WINDOW","width=500,height=500")
```

i am almost to the end of the project but this problem is still pending

Comment: can you show new created url?

Answer (score 0):

Add the '_blank' parameter to 'window.open()' for opening in a new tab:

```
var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
win.focus();
```

Comment: still the same result

Answer (score 0):

Replace the "NEW WINDOW" with '_blank'

window.open("examples2.aspx?q=12&q1=12","_blank","width=500,height=500")

In IE try changing the browser settings..

Go to Internet Options>>Tabs>>Select the tab behaviour settings >>Click Ok